# Google Sheets IMPORTRANGE and QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I'm new to Sheets and the query function as of last night, so don't know the terminology etc - sorry!

I have two workbooks, a master and a template.  I need the templete to pull specific data from the master when Col2 matches a particular number.  I have it working great if i manually input the number, but don't want to have to do this everytime I give a copy of the template to a new job.  This number in Col2 is unique to each of the templates I give to a new job, and the number will already be manually input into cell J16 of the template.  I want the code to pull the number from `J16` and search rather than me telling it what the number is everytime.  The code I have that works with the manual input number, in this case 4032 is below.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Vince.

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1yTp3SajbKovHf_Wjx7CHO9FsIPeQGvmdMytQIkr9gog","Invoices"),"select Col1, Col5, Col11 where Col2 = 4032")`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the number (any) from J16 into your query?

Use:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("file_id","Invoices"),"select Col1, Col5, Col11 where Col2 = " & J16)`

or better:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("file_id","Invoices"),a1)`

where a1 is:

`="select Col1, Col5, Col11 where Col2 = " & J16`

Comment: Thank you Max, this works as intended and I'm able to see the errors I made!  I didn't close out the quotes so it makes sense now.  I can't understand why my logic couldn't get me there on my own, so thank you.

Also, your suggestion of placing the 'select' text into another cell is another great idea I hadn't thought of.

I appreciate you taking the time to help.